# Developing for Windows 7: deployment seems an issue

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-installer

I have remarked that I have installation problem when I download some commercial software and install them on Windows 7. For example the message about data1.cab not found. I tried to register cabview.dll but it didn't fix.

So what do you need to do to insure that your software will deploy for sure on Windows 7 ?

For example this application doesn't install on Windows 7 even when I did it with admin priviledge:
http://www.bizagi.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=27&catid=5&Itemid=98

What did they forget to do ?

Comment: I mean what should I include as dll registry etc. specific to win7 to insure it deploys correctly.

Comment: You don't need anything special, other than a manifest if your application requires administrative privileges. Generally, if you have deployment problems, you're doing something wrong. Fix that instead.

Comment: I have any app myself at the moment I'm talking about some commercial apps I tried to install on Windows 7 like http://www.bizagi.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=27&catid=5&Itemid=98 so what did they wrong ? Forgot a manifest file ?

Comment: There are 2 applications on that webpage and their specs and screenshots indicate they support Vista and 7.  I installed the smaller package on my x64 Windows 7 machine and it seemed to install no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example this application doesn't install on Windows 7 even when I did it with admin priviledge

The three most likely reasons are that they goofed and didn't test correctly. Or you have downloaded (or been given) the wrong version. Or you may have a corrupted or incomplete installer. Registering *cabview.dll* won't solve the problem of *data1.cab* being missing (a *cab* file is a [cabinet file](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361921.aspx), it is a container for other files, much like a zip file).

> So what do you need to do to insure that your software will deploy for sure on Windows 7 ?

Ensuring that your application is packaged using an industry standard MSI creation package is a good start. There are many applications out there that do this, such as InstallShield, Wise, WiX, InstallAware - just to name a few.

The very best thing you can do though is to author your install package so that it meets the [Windows Installer and Logo Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372825%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). What happens with this is that you submit your built installer (with documentation) to an independant third party certification company who will then test it and decide if it meets the criteria laid down by Microsoft to say that your application installs and runs correctly on the target operating system. The tests are all slightly different depending upon which operating system you are seeking certification for<sup>1</sup>.

To ensure you have the best chance of installing correctly (and passing certification should you submit for it), you should follow the [Windows Installer Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204770%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - these apply no matter which application you use to build your installer. You can also run the required tests<sup>2</sup> yourself by using [Msival2.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to run [ICE (Internal Consistency Evaluator)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369554%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tests. The installer tools and ICE files can all be found in the [Microsoft Windows Software Development Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

<sup>1</sup>Passing these tests also achieves a Microsoft Partner Competency if you are part of the [Microsoft Partner Program](https://partner.microsoft.com).

<sup>2</sup>The same tests that the certification company would run

Comment: Thanks for my education as I am novice at this :). I'll also go to their forum and ask them to repackage their stuff for Windows 7 more correctly: I have downloaded it multiple times and test it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If it won't install on Win7 then they probably didn't test on Win7.  Not just the installer but the application also.    Fixing the installer isn't a magic bullet.

I've helped many teams migrate from one OS to another.  Win3.11 to NT 4.0, XP to Vista/7 and so on.  I've yet to see a project that only had installer problems and nothing wrong with their app.

After all, if they didn't obey platform requirements for the installer, why would they have for the application?